Where and how Internet Explorer stores desktop icons for hyperlinks
When a website is opened in Internet Explorer and the URL is dragged from the address bar onto the Windows' desktop, an icon is created. The image of this icon in most cases looks like the website's favicon. These icons persist even after IE cache has been deleted. Where and how Windows OS stores these icons?

May I ask why you're running IE in 2024?

Windows is surprisingly sneaky here: it stores the favicon image using an NTFS Alternate Data Stream as a child of the .url file.
The stream-name is Pages.url:favicon:$DATA.
This is documented in the MS-FSCC specification.
Obviously this only works on NTFS, whereas I distinctly remember desktop .url shortcuts having favicons when I was using Windows 98 (which used FAT, not NTFS) - I don't know how it worked on Windows 9x.

Scott Hanselman wrote an article about this back in 2010.

I don't have the full answer, but I can tell you what I know.
First, I know that Windows Explorer caches thumbnails and icons. So when you clear the IE cache, Windows Explorer will still have a copy of the icon that it can display on the Desktop. For completeness, you should clear both the IE icon cache and the Windows Explorer icon cache.
Second, I know that IE generates the local icon files from the icon files on the target website. Specifically, IE looks for a <link rel="icon" ... tag in the target webpage's HTML and downloads the corresponding icon image from the website.
Now, I don't know where IE saves the downloaded icon files, but I can tell you how to find out. Internet links on the Desktop are actually just local text files. The contents of an internet link file looks something like the following:
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.someaddress.com/
WorkingDirectory=C:\WINDOWS\
ShowCommand=7
IconIndex=1
IconFile=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\url.dll
Modified=20F06BA06D07BD014D
HotKey=1601

The line that starts with IconFile is the part that will interest you. This line tells Windows Explorer where on your computer to find that link's icon. I believe that C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\url.dll is the default value fr this field.
If you were to open up one of the links on your Desktop using Notepad, you could see exactly where IE saved the icon file for that specific link.
Because Notepad doesn't know that internet link files are actually just text files, you'll have to use the All files option in Notepad's File > Open menu. The default for that setting is Text Documents (*.txt), which will prevent you from seeing the internet link files in the File > Open menu.

@ Aaron Stanek I tried to open internet links before with PSpad but all I get is this:[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://somewebsite08676.10439821   There is no other information about working directory or iconfile
